# How do I filter results from Google Places getCurrentPlace?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using Google Place's getCurrentPlace API and want to filter my results to certain types of places.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While getCurrentPlace does take a filter parameter, the filter is very restricted-  it only allows filtering by business that are open now or by specific place ids (useful if you want to filter by a list of predefined locations).  In a piece of bad design this class is final, so you cannot extend it.  You have to do your filtering after calling their API.  This is a bit wasteful memory wise, but there's no avoiding it.

The following code filters a PlaceLikelihoodBuffer by type.  It allows you to specified multiple allowed types, and disallowed types.  Disallowed takes precedence over allowed-  for example if you specify allowed to be restaurants and disallowed to be grocery stores, it would reject any cafes in grocery stores.

```
package com.gabesechan.android.reusable.location;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBuffer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class PlaceTypeFilter {

    private Set<Integer> mAllowedTypes;
    private Set<Integer> mDisallowedTypes;

    public PlaceTypeFilter(int allowedTypes[], int disallowedTypes[]) {
        mAllowedTypes = new HashSet<>();
        for(int type : allowedTypes) {
            mAllowedTypes.add(type);
        }
        mDisallowedTypes = new HashSet<>();
        for(int type : disallowedTypes) {
            mDisallowedTypes.add(type);
        }
    }

    public  boolean hasMatchingType(Place place) {
        List<Integer> types = place.getPlaceTypes();
        for (int type : types) {
            if (mDisallowedTypes.contains(type)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (int type : types) {
            if (mAllowedTypes.contains(type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<PlaceLikelihood> filteredPlaces(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer places) {
        List<PlaceLikelihood> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for(PlaceLikelihood likelihood : places) {
            if(hasMatchingType(likelihood.getPlace())) {
                results.add(likelihood);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```